# Can I install the Stylesheet from a Mathematica Journal article?

Tags: stylesheet

A discussion from 2012 suggested that it should be possible to download an article from the Mathematica Journal and install its stylesheet locally.

I can download the .nb file but can not seem to install the stylesheet. Is there now some type of protection that prevents this?

Is there some other source for stylesheets that print to PDF in ways that are readable/attractive?

Comment: Would you include a link to the Style Sheet to which you refer, please?

Answer (score 8):

- Download the article as notebook and open it
- Go to menu item `Format > Edit Stylesheet`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- In the style sheet choose `File > Save as` and save the stylesheet
- Open a new notebook and Go to menu item `Format > Edit Stylesheet` again
- Push the `Install Stylesheet...` button

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- The name you enter here will be the name listed in the stylesheet list:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The stylesheet is now available in the `Format > Stylesheet` menu

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the styles from this stylesheet:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Comment: @paul You're welcome